# Find a match pattern of any digit and space with any character in a string and replace with | in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, match

$str = "COVId 1234 SARS 4567 EBOLA 2332";

new string:

$str = "COVId 1234 | SARS 4567 | EBOLA 2332";

Comment: where is your attempt?

Comment: to explode the |

Comment: I mean the php code you've wrote so far.

Comment: This is big data I parsed from a PDF but the whole document comes without format it should be a preg_replace() but I cant find the correct pattern \d\s[a-zA-Z]

Comment: $pattern = '\d\s[a-zA-Z]';
$str = preg_replace($pattern, '|', $str);

Comment: There is no `|`. Do mean implode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = "COVId 1234 | SARS 4567 | EBOLA 2332";
preg_replace('([a-zA-Z]+ \d+ )', '$0 |', $str);
echo $str; // COVId 1234 | SARS 4567 | EBOLA 2332
```

`[a-ZA-Z]+` matches all alphabetic chars.

is just to match a space.

`\d+` matches digit**s**. Note the plural.